# errorlevel value after ping (Windows)

Tags: windows, ping, errorlevel

Need help understanding the following. After running ping if it was succesful %errorlevel% gets set to 0, otherwise gets set to 1. One way of testing networking connectivity. However i found out that if i ping a computer in our domain that at the moment of the ping is not connected (i physically removed the cable) i still get %errorlevel% set to ZERO. Ping shows no packet loss, but it displays a "computer not available" as part of the responde message. Who is sending the response packet? I ping by host name, not by IP. I run the ping command in a Windows 7 machine. The networking being run under Windows Server 2008.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: *"Who is sending the response packet?"* - Presumably the name server, that does the name lookup.

Comment: Sounds like the "destination host unreachable" reply, sent by your own machine's network stack when there is no response to the ARP request.  As a practical workaround, try something like `ping n.n.n.n | findstr bytes=32` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable: no, if the name lookup fails no packets are sent (so no packet loss statistics) and the errorlevel is set to 1.